# Run e2e test with simulation of k8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, k3s

we want to create e2e test (integration test ) for our applications on k8s and we want to use
minikube but it seems that there is no proper (maintained or official ) docker file for minikube. at least 
I didn’t find any…In addition I see [k3s](https://k3s.io)  and not sure which is better to run e2e test on k8s ?

I found this docker file but when I build it it fails with errors

https://aspenmesh.io/2018/01/building-istio-with-minikube-in-a-container-and-jenkins/

`e - –no-install-recommends error`

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no official way to run minikube from within a container. Here's a two months old [quote](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3192#issuecomment-496186427) from one of minikube's contributors:

> It is on the roadmap. For now, it is VM based.

If you decide to go with using a VM image containing minikube, there are some guides how to do it out there. Here's one called "[Using Minikube as part of your CI/CD flow](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/minikube-ci/)
".

Alternatively, there's a project called [MicroK8S](https://microk8s.io/) backed by Canonical. In a **Kubernetes Podcast [ep. 39](https://kubernetespodcast.com/episode/039-minikube/)** from February, [Dan Lorenc](https://github.com/dlorenc) mentions this:

> MicroK8s is really exciting. That's based on some new features of recent Ubuntu distributions to let you run a Kubernetes environment in an **isolated fashion without using a virtual machine**. So if you happen to be on one of those Ubuntu distributions and can take advantage of those features, then I would definitely recommend MicroK8s.

I don't think he's referring to running minikube in a container though, but I am not fully sure: I'd enter a Ubuntu container, try to install microk8s as a package, then see what happens.

That said, unless there's a compelling reason you want to run kubernetes from within a container and you are ready to spend the time going the possible rabbit hole – I think these days running minikube, k3s or microk8s from within a VM should be the safest bet if you want to get up and running with a CI/CD pipeline relatively quickly.

Comment: thanks, you write "running minikube, k3s or microk8s from within a VM should be the safest bet " , do you mean on travis or circleci ?

Comment: @RaynD yes, I mean travis or circleci. Or perhaps even a dedicated instance running minikube in GCP / AWS.

The article linked above called "Using Minikube as part of your CI/CD flow" has a full CircleCI config sample available to study.

Answer (score 1):

As to the problem you encountered when building image from this particular Dockerfile...

> I found this docker file but when I build it it fails with errors
>
> https://aspenmesh.io/2018/01/building-istio-with-minikube-in-a-container-and-jenkins/
>
> e - –no-install-recommends error
>
> any idea ?

notice that:

```
--no-install-recommends install
```

and

```
–no-install-recommends install
```

are two completely different strings. So that the error you get:

```
E: Invalid operation –no-install-recommends
```

is the result you've copied content of your Dockerfile from [here](https://aspenmesh.io/2018/01/building-istio-with-minikube-in-a-container-and-jenkins/) and you should have rather copied it from [github](https://gist.github.com/andrewjjenkins/798f5c736a187d616d256095662c0a76) (you can even click `raw` button there to be 100% sure you copy totally plain text without any additional formatting, changed encoding etc.)